# how to install theme in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, theme, installation

How to install the following theme from Magento Connect:

https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/free-theme-women-fashion-by-pagayo.html

there is install click there but when click it, it give just a link... what should I do with that ?!

detailed steps and full path to the configuration ta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recent versions of Magento 2 does not have magento connect functionality to install theme and extensions.(It may be added in future.)

Also the theme mentioned by you is compatible only for Magento 1x versions.

Please refer this url [Magento 2 themes](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-general.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can't install Magento 2 theme from Magento connect.

Unzip the downloaded theme and upload the files to the public root directory of your Magento 2 store.

Then run these commands in the root directory of your store:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Go to **CONTENT → Configuration** to activate your theme.