# How to install paid theme in magento 2 online store

Tags: magento-2.1, theme, installation

I want to know how to install paid theme in magento 2.

I want a tutorial which show me all actions step by step.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to install theme in Magento 2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/105672/how-to-install-theme-in-magento-2)

Answer (score 1):

Have you done the steps from the Magento dev docs?
Ususally the way you can do it is the following

**To install a theme manually:**

Make sure that the directory structure you are copying is `<VendorName>/<theme>`. And all the theme files are in the `<theme>` directory.

Copy this directory to the /app/design/frontend directory.

**Register a theme**

After you create or install a theme, open the Magento Admin or reload any Magento Admin page. This way the theme gets registered and added to the database.

To make sure the theme is registered, in the Magento Admin navigate to Content > Design > Themes. If a theme is registered, it is displayed in the list of available themes.

Source: [Dev Docs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-install.html)